# Transistor for 4-20 mA voltage drop resistor connection?

Tags: current-measurement, 4-20ma

This is for converting a 4-20 mA current loop signal to a voltage. Is it okay to connect the resistor for measuring voltage drop with a transistor to allow for switching between voltage and current measurement mode or is this a bad idea? Usually jumpers are used but I'd like to make it software controllable.

Answer (score 1):

Using a resistor in series with a 4- 20 ma signal is common practice to measure the voltage drop.

Something like a 300 ohm resistor will give you a 1.2 V signal at 4 ma and 6 V at 20 ma.

Can you provide more description of how you are using the transistor?  Possibly provide a circuit diagram.  It sounds as if you are trying to get the transistor to switch at a discrete signal level.

Comment: Using it just as you said... I just want to make sure it's okay and doesn't alter the signal. Figured people had done it before so I thought I'd ask.

Comment: I do it all the time.  300 ohm resistor to measure a 5 volt range and 1.5 ohm resistor to measure a mv range.  Basic Ohms law I * R will give you the voltage at a given ma range.

Comment: What do you mean by the 1.5 ohm resistor? Also, by 300 i assume you meant 250 since 5V/20mA = 250 ohm?

Comment: A 250 Ohm resistor will give you a 4 volt range over 4-20 ma.  250 * .02=5 V  and  250 * .004= 1V.  I use a 300 Ohm resistor which is 300 * .02 = 6V  and 300 * .004 = 1.2 V (4.8 Volt range).

Comment: A 1.5 Ohm resistor will give you 30 mv at 20 ma and 6 mv at 4 ma.  1.5 * .02 = .03v and 1.5 * .004 = .006v.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's a constant current so E= I*R. So long as you don't exceed the voltage compliance of the source or inject errors (such as leakage or base current) into the signal, you're golden.

You'll have to measure the voltage across the sense resistor differentially, naturally.

Comment: What do you think about using a mosfet instead of a bjt so I don't have to worry about base leakage?

Comment: Edit your question to include a schematic and I'll be able to comment. \$I_{CBO}\$ would be more important, and only in the voltage configuration, as I visualize it.

Comment: Here's what I'm thinking:
<4-20mA in>----transistor-------<ADC input>
                   |
                <resistor>
                   |
                  GND

Comment: Then you definitely would want a MOSFET.